# Play videoView without stopping background music

Tags: android, audio, view, kotlin

I have a music launched on my phone and when I'm launching my application a VideoView starts with a mp4.

The problem is that VideoView make my music stop. I have to manually restart it .

Is there a way to play an mp4 in my VideoView over the music in background and without stopping it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible.In android device we cant play music and video at the same time using different player.One media player only executed at a time.

For more details Refer [Media app architecture overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview)

Comment: I heard about audioFocus , my application request focus so my music in background stop. Do you know a way to not give the audio focus to the application and then let the music in background plays ?

Comment: When your music is background ,you can perform read message,text chat,using other apps but when you are going to play video it will stop all previous activity of media players.

Answer (score 1):

Like in humans , you cant speak 2 languages in the same time.

There is always a way, if you own a ANDROID

Double Music Player plays two songs at the same time.